# The limit needed to find the derivative of e^sin(x) at x=1.

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm trying to figure out why this:
[image: answer]

is the answer to this problem: [image: problem]

What are the steps that take the numerator from $e^{\sin(1+h)} - e^{\sin(1)}$ to  $e^{\sin(h)} - 1$?

Comment: You are correct, the solution is for $x=0$, not $x=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, x = 0 makes a lot more sense. I guess it's a mistake in my book. Thanks!

Comment: To write $\sin(x)$ in LaTeX, use `\sin(x)`. To write $e^{\sin(x)}$, use `e^{\sin(x)}`.

Comment: Are you sure of the the first limit?

Comment: @science You're right, I think the term in that expression should be $e^{cos (h)}$ by my computation. Then the limit makes sense.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: That's what I meant.

Comment: @science That's the answer provided in my book, but I'm not so sure that it's correct anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As science pointed out in his/her comment, I think you made an error with the limit.

$e^{sin(1+h)}$ - $e^{sin(1)}$$\to$ $e^{sin(1)cos(h)+ cos(1)sin(h)}$-$e^{sin(1)}$=$e^{sin(1)cos(h)}e^{cos(1)sin(h)}$-$e^{sin(1)}$. Multiplying through by  $e^{-(cos(1)sin(h))}$ gives $e^{0} e^{sin (h)cos(1)}-e^{0}$ $\to$ $e^{sin (h)}e^{cos(1)}- 1$. Now you just follow through with the limit. Clearly, as $h \rightarrow$ 0, $e^{sin(h)}\rightarrow 1$. This gives the correct limit.

Comment: I reformatted this to look better. A correction: $\sin(1+h) = \sin(1)\cos(h)+\cos(1)\sin(h)$

Comment: Crap,the addition formula. Thanks,I revised it.The logic is still basically correct,I just had to change and lengthen the computation somewhat.It should be correct now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't $e^{\sin(1)\cos(h)+\cos(1)\sin(h)}$ expand only to $e^{\sin(1)\cos(h)}e^{\cos(1)\sin(h)}$?

Comment: I gave it one more polishing. If it's not correct now, I give up. I got my own website to finish,anyway.......lol